# Condense google sheets script to prevent 6 minute time out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an app script that all the sudden started hitting the 6min execution timer in google sheets and need some help condensing the functions if possible.

Its objective is to pull a list of names in a column (list A), compare that list of names to a list of names spread across multiple columns (List B), and then grab the list of names UNDER the list of names (from list B) that it matches from list A, and paste the combined list in a different column while filtering duplicates.

```
function FINDMATCH() { //Function to check each columns on "Sheet2" to see if it has names that match any names on the "Main List"
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Roster");
  var mainList = [].concat.apply([], main.getRange("AP4:AP").getValues()).filter(String); //Main list data starts at AP4
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("rbe"); //Name of the Sheet2
  var result = mainList;
  for(col=1; col <= sheet2.getDataRange().getLastColumn(); col++){
    var currentCol = [].concat.apply([], sheet2.getRange(1,col,8,1).getValues()).filter(String);
    mainList.forEach(function(list){
      currentCol.forEach(function(data){
        if(data == list){
          result.push(currentCol.toString());
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  var data = FILTER(result.toString().trim().split(","));
  main.getRange("AQ4:AQ").clearContent(); //Clears the old "Imported List" data before pasting updated list of names
  main.getRange(4,43,data.length,1).setValues(data); //Updates the "Imported List". Current col "43" = AQ
}

function FILTER(array) { //Function that filters duplicate names
  var data = array;
  var newData = [];
  var formattedData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row === newData[j] && row === newData[j]) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  newData.forEach(function(i){
    formattedData.push([i]);
  });
  return formattedData;
}
```

Judging by the debugger the main problem seems to occur here:

```
for(col=1; col <= sheet2.getDataRange().getLastColumn(); col++){
    var currentCol = [].concat.apply([], sheet2.getRange(1,col,8,1).getValues()).filter(String);
```

Test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6ZcVPmt1nitncxQCmVzMh06Aa20ObQ1ZEpoFGOxMYk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). You may also try the [Blank sheet maker here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383).

Comment: Seems like you're making getrange calls on every loop iteration. Among Google's [recommended practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) is to batch requests so you should get everything you need at once and then work on it as an array. Can you share a sample sheet so we can test?

Comment: @Daniel added test sheet to main post.  The current formula works quickly on this one because there isn't a lot else going on.  There is a lot going on in the sheet it mainly lives in so I still need a way to make this more efficient.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. Your showing script works fine. Is my understanding correct? 2. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet using your showing script, why the value of `Bname 2` is not included in the result values? I cannot understand the logic for it.

Comment: @Tanaike I actually don't know why Bname 2 isn't showing... My only guess is the filter is catching it somehow, that shouldn't be happening.  And yes the script works, but I was looking for a way to make it more efficient.   This is a very small table, where the one it runs on is much larger dataset and gets timed out.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I actually don't know why Bname 2 isn't showing...` and `And yes the script works`, I cannot understand your goal. You don't want to retrieve `Bname 2` in your sample Spreadsheet? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the detailed logic for achieving your goal? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your goal. I apologize for this. First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.